# Displays the total number of products

Tags: php, wordpress, html, woocommerce

What code use to display the total number of products? I want to make a section with icons on the main page of my store and it would be great to include something like that.

Best Regards

Comment: total number of products in store OR in a specific category? and what code till now you tried , show there ?

Comment: None. Because I can't find anything any solution :/. Total numbers of products but both cases can be useful.

Comment: check the answer, using that you can get total number of products in your store

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In case you want to show total number of published products in your store, use the following code:

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'post_status' => 'publish', 
'posts_per_page' => -1 );
$products = new WP_Query( $args );
echo $products->found_posts;
```

It returns the total number of published products in your store.

Comment: One liner
```$total_products = (new WP_Query(['post_type' => 'product', 'post_status' => 'publish']))->found_posts;```

Comment: And more general function approach ```$total = fn($post_type, $post_status) => (new WP_Query(['post_type' => $post_type, 'post_status' => $post_status]))->found_posts;
``` Call like this: ```$total('product', 'publish')```